# Select multiple point geoJSON data (angular 2 leaflet)

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, geojson

currently i am develop a map using leaflet and retrieve data from geoserver to add layer into my map.. after add layer into map the output will look like this

[image]

how can i select multiple point and and highlight the selected point. i already try with my code and the result is nothing happen.

here is my code **[plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/OYybb79eN8A3Miyjwcm3/)**

sory if u guys dont understand my question and can directly ask me.

thanks

Comment: Please, edit your question adding the code.

Comment: @gp_sflover i already add code in my question ..here once more https://embed.plnkr.co/OYybb79eN8A3Miyjwcm3/

Comment: @paan Providing a live example like your plunker is very nice indeed. However it is generally expected to paste the "problematic" part of your code directly in your question body as well, so that people can immediately reason about it, rather than having to look into an external site they might not be familiar with, and which could be down or even shut down in the future.